# When i use difftime() in R and what i think is the proper setup I still get strange time values

Tags: r, datetime, timestamp, difftime

I load a dataset from excel

```
library(readxl)
df<-read_excel("excel_file.XLSX")
```

In the file there is a separate date column  as Posixct

```
str(df$datecol)
```

I also have a time column that in R gets loaded as a date time. To bring it back as time I do........

```
df$Timecol<-format(df$Timecol,"%H:%M:%S")
```

However it turns into a character. This is where i think the problem lies

```
str(STOP_DATA$`Stop Frisk Time`)
```

I would think this part resolves the situation

```
df$merge_date_time<-as.POSIXct(paste(df$Datecol, df$TimeCol), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

The date and time is then combined. What i want to do now is reference a timestamp column that is a Poxict data type.

```
str(df$Timestamp)
```

I would like to then find the time difference between them

```
df$TIME_SINCE <- difftime(df$Timestamp, df$merge_date_time, tz="UTC", units = "mins" )
```

but I end up with weird numbers that don't make sense. My guess its the Character data type for time. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You're right, `format` gives you a character vector as a result. Use `as.Date` or `lubridate::as_date` instead. To get the time difference between two timestamps, try `as.numeric(timestamp2 - timestamp1, units = "minutes")`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding out that this works

```
df$date_time<-paste(df$date, format(as.POSIXct(df$time), '%T'))
```

I removed the portion below from the script as it changed the file into a character.

```
df$Timecol<-format(df$Timecol,"%H:%M:%S")
```

I accepted the obscure POSIXT default with the proper time and odd dates (1899-12-31) and what the script did was replace 1899-12-31 with the proper correstponding df$date column.